# I can't get mock to work

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

I'm trying to use a mock for unit testing with Python/Django but I just can't get it to work. The mock acts like it has never been called.

tests.py

```
from my_module import my_library
my_library = MagicMock()

class MyTest(TestCase):
    def test_add(self):
        acronym = 'TEST'

        m = MyModel(acronym=acronym)
        m.save()

        my_library.add.assert_called_with(acronym=acronym)
```

my_library.py

```
def add(acronym):
    # Processing...
```

models.py

```
class MyModel(Model):
    acronym = CharField(max_length=4)

    def save(self):
        my_library.add(acronym=self.acronym)

        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

My library works, I know the function add is correctly called. But the mock doesn't seem to work because it just raises en exception when I run the unit tests:

```
AssertionError: Expected call: add(acronym='TEST')
Not called
```

I think I don't correctly use the mock thing. Can anyone help or give advice please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because it is never called. The first line of your program does this:

```
my_library = __import__("my_module")
```

The next line just overshadows the first. It does not alter my_module in any way, thus all your other code just calls the original code instead of the mock.

Take a look at `mock.patch` instead. Either like this:

```
from mock import patch
import my_module as my_library

class MyTest(TestCase):
    def test_add(self):
        acronym = 'TEST'
        with patch.object(my_library, 'add') as add_method:   
            m = MyModel(acronym=acronym)
            m.save()
            add_method.assert_called_with(acronym=acronym)
```

Or using the original module name:

```
from mock import patch

class MyTest(TestCase):
    def test_add(self):
        acronym = 'TEST'
        with patch('my_module.add') as add_method:   
            m = MyModel(acronym=acronym)
            m.save()
            add_method.assert_called_with(acronym=acronym)
```

Comment: Thanks for explanations, though I already tried to implement alecxe's solution with mock.patch but the mock was still not called.

Comment: Still doesn't work even after trying the second solution. The mock is just not called.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `patch`:

```
from mock import patch
from my_module import my_library


class MyTest(TestCase):
    def test_add(self):
        acronym = 'TEST'

        with patch('my_library.add') as add_method:   
            m = MyModel(acronym=acronym)
            m.save()

            add_method.assert_called_with(acronym=acronym)
```

Hope that works for you.

Comment: Any other solution? I tried again several times but still doesn't work. The mock is not called at all.